# Create a file and then delete in java

Tags: java, javascript, hibernate

My requirement is there is an export button,onclick the data in the database is loaded and then converted into a .csv ,.doc  or .html file ,which can be opened or saved somehere, this needs to be converted into a file , save it in the local path and uploaded to the SFTP server and deleted from the loacl path.  My code goes like this .....

```
public String a(String tableName, String format,String jsondataAsString,String jsonKeyName,String userName,
            String password, String hostName,String remotePath) throws IOException{
        userName="a";
        password="a";
        hostName="10.100.10.100";
        remotePath="/tmp";
        System.out.println("TableName-->" +tableName);
        System.out.println("Format-->" +format);
        System.out.println("JsonData-->" +jsondataAsString);
        System.out.println("userName-->" +userName);
        System.out.println("password-->" +password);
        System.out.println("hostname-->" +hostName);
        System.out.println("RemotePath-->" +remotePath);
        String mimeType = null;
        String fileName = null;
        String seperator = null;        
        String lineSeperator = null;
        boolean isFileTransferComplete=true;
        OutputStream f1 =null;

        if (format.equalsIgnoreCase("CSV")) {
            fileName = tableName + ".csv";
            mimeType = "application/CSV";
            seperator = ",";
            lineSeperator = "\n";



        } else if (format.equalsIgnoreCase("Word")) {
            fileName = tableName + ".doc";
            mimeType = "application/msword";
            seperator = " ";
            lineSeperator = "\n\n";
        } else {

            fileName = tableName + ".html";
            mimeType = "application/html";
            seperator = "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            lineSeperator = "<br><br>";
        }
        String localfilePath="D:/aaa/" +fileName;
        String error="";
    try{
        String data = convertJsonToString(jsondataAsString, seperator, jsonKeyName,lineSeperator,format);
        if (data == null || data.length() == 0) {
            data = "[BLANK]";
        }
       boolean isFileTobeDeleted=true;
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.out.println("Buffer-->" +buffer);

        buffer.flush();
        buffer.write(data.getBytes());

        f1 = new FileOutputStream(localfilePath);
        buffer.writeTo(f1);

        isFileTransferComplete = new SFTPHandler(hostName,
                PicoEmsGuiConstants.SFTP_Port, userName, password)
                .uploadFile(remotePath,localfilePath);
        System.out.println("FileTransfer" +isFileTransferComplete);

          File target = new File(localfilePath);  

             target.delete();


         }
         System.out.println("isFileTobeDeleted" +isFileTobeDeleted);



        }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Exception :::>" +e.getMessage());

        }finally{
            f1.close();
        }

        return isFileTransferComplete+"--"+ remotePath;

    }
```

I am able to create file but after the completion of uploading unable to delete form the loacl path...Can anyone tell me where i am goin wrong

Comment: You probably want a temporary file, look in the API there's support for it.

Comment: Why has the `f1.close()` been deleted from the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't you have to close the stream and then attempt to delete it?

```
finally {
    f1.close();
    if(file != null && file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
}
```