# What is referring to my file, preventing me from calling .delete() successfully?

Tags: java, exception, delete-file

I am making a game and have started to work on a class called SaveManager, so far I have had no problems except when it comes to deleting the game.

My problem is this, .delete() returns false the majority of times, without calling an exception.

If I make a loop (below) it does eventually delete, despite me not actually changing any variables or references and the game loop itself definitely doesn't deal with the files at all, so it isn't "releasing" the file itself at any point.

```
public void delete(File save)
    {
        while (save.exists() && !save.delete())
            {
                i++;
            }
        new infoBox("Times delete called: " + i, "delete method in saveManager");
```

So my question is: If the reference is not from one of my classes how do I find it and remove it, allowing me to remove the above loop, which basically hijacks the game until the file is gone.

Here is the code which does deal with the file, in case I am in fact doing something wrong (God Forbid!) I'm pretty sure this does "release" the save file in question...

```
private void save()
{
    ObjectOutputStream OOS = null;
    BufferedOutputStream BOS = null;
    FileOutputStream FOS = null;
    try
        {
            File saveFile = new File(saveDirectory + hub.world.saveName + ".dat");
            OOS = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(saveFile, false)));

            OOS.write... (List of Objects & Strings here)
            OOS.flush();
            OOS.close(); 

            game.saved = true; //Used for warning message on exit
            this.setSavesList();
        }
    catch (Exception e)
        {
                new errorWindow(e, "SaveFile, I/O error");
        }
    finally
        {
            try
                {
                    FOS.flush();
                    FOS.close();
                    BOS.flush();
                    BOS.close();
                    OOS.flush();
                    OOS.close();
                }
            catch (IOException e)
                {
                    hub.frame.errorWindow(e, "Problem closing streams");
                }
        }

}
```

Comment: You need to work on your naming conventions!

Comment: You talk about delete but the above code has a function named save.

Comment: @adarshr Sorry for any sloppy naming conventions, I've taught myself Java and it is my first language too!

Comment: @GeorgeKastrinin The delete function simply checks the file exists then calls the while loop I mentioned above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One general thing to check while dealing with files is if you're closing any opened streams before attempting to delete it.

You can't delete a file unless the stream opened is closed.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091074/create-a-file-and-then-delete-in-java/7091139#7091139).

Comment: The "while(!save.delete());" seems to hint that a stream is indeed not  always closed. The while-loop succeeds just later when the stream is finally closed by the garbage collector.

Comment: I didn't ensure the InputStream was properly closed!

Answer (score 3):

You are creating three streams, and only closing the top-most one (OOS).

You should close each stream manually. I think that will fix your problem.

Also, it's often considered good practice to put the close() in a finally block, so it definitely happens.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
try 
{
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        OOS = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);

        OOS.write... (List of Objects & Strings here)
        OOS.flush();
        OOS.close(); 

        bos.flush();
        bos.close();

        game.saved = true; //Used for warning message on exit
        this.setSavesList();
} catch (IOException ioe)
{
}
finally
{
  fos.close();
}
```

Otherwise, you might flush the object output stream, and the data just gets stuck in the buffered output stream, and never gets written to the file output stream.

Comment: When you `OOS.close()` it flushes first and then closes bos and fos.

Comment: Does not closing the ObjectOuputStream, which contains the other two streams, free them up for garbage collection? Will they still be accessing the file/do they ever access the file independently?

Comment: +1 For `finally`. In the original code an exception in `OOS.write()` would not close the file, this does.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks for the reminder. I know that BufferedOutputStream closes the underlying stream, but the JavaDoc for ObjectOutputStream doesn't specify. I can't find a canonical spec for it (not that 5 minutes with google is particularly exhaustive)

Comment: It does say explicitly other than "releases resources" however the close method of ObjectOutputStream is `public close() throws IOException { flush(); clear(); bout.close(); }`

Comment: @PeterLawrey So I don't need to close or flush the other Streams if I flush and close the ObjectOutputStream?

Comment: @Sebastian Troy, closing the outer most Stream flushes and closes everything else. (Avoiding it is more tricky ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Awesome, thanks, so if all of my Streams are closed, what can explain the file still being referred to?

Comment: You are either not closing the file when you think you are or you are trying to delete the file in code which is executed before the close().

Answer (score 2):

Here's a food for thought...from the code above, you have used a try-catch block...my guess is that one of the above operations is throwing an exception because of which the out.close() operation is getting skipped...why not add a "finally" block and close the stream there...it would definitely help you save the trouble.

Comment: Thanks I will do that, as for one of the operations throwing an exception, they don't, I have checked and there are no problems with this block of code throwing exceptions, thanks for the pointer though :D

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your file is actually being created?  In the code snippet above you have while(!save.delete())  but later on you seem to refer to it as saveFile, these may be two different files!  I would first check to see if the file even exists on the disk by doing an

```
if(!saveFile.exists()) {
do something here
}
```

if it doesnt exist, a delete will just return false, you cannot delete a file that does not exist.

Comment: The saves are definitely working, as I can save and load the game many times without any problems at all, also the while loop would freeze my game forever, but instead it does eventually delete the file, also I do check that it exists before hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking the result of delete you also need to check whether the files exists. Obviously if there is not file or it has already been deleted, delete() will return false. ;)

Comment: I do check it exists before I call delete, sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: On Linux you can confirm the file really is still open by looking at the `/proc/{process-id}/fd/*` This doesn't tell you why but its a start.